# During the operation of a ZooKeeper cluster, are all nodes interconnected?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

In terms of ZooKeeper, I've already studied features and scenarios such as client services, state synchronization, and internal elections.
However, there are some doubts that I haven't successfully retrieved answers for, specifically as follows:
In the data write scenario of ZooKeeper, during the state synchronization process, how is the synchronization among multiple Followers carried out? Is it the Leader synchronizing to multiple Followers, or is it a chain synchronization like Leader -> Follower -> Follower?
In the election scenario of ZooKeeper, are all nodes interconnected?

I hope someone can answer my doubts.
I'm unable to discern the accuracy of the content narrated by GPT.